# When JavaScript is called input text is deleted?

Tags: javascript

Im using the following to update the Latitude and Longitude of a delivery postcode.

Code works perfectly except when the script is called it deletes the postcode from the input box.

Can someone tell me why this is?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  var geo = new GClientGeocoder(); 
  function getAddress(search) {
    geo.getLocations(search, function (result)
      { 
        if (result.Status.code == G_GEO_SUCCESS) {
          var p = result.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates;
          var lat=p[1];
          var lng=p[0];
          var dcMessage = '<span style="color:#990000">Post Code Successfully GeoCoded</span>'
          var dcHiddenOutput = '<input type="hidden" name="lat" value="' +lat+ '"><input type="hidden" name="lng" value="' +lng+ '">';
          document.getElementById("ConfirmOrder").innerHTML += dcMessage;
          document.getElementById("UpdateGeo").innerHTML += dcHiddenOutput;
        } 
      }
    );
  }
  function theNext() {
    var addresses = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
      getAddress(addresses);
  }
//]]>
</script>

<form id="UpdateGeo" method="get" action="updateGeocode.asp">
<input id="myInput" name="PostCode" style="text-transform:uppercase" />&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox"  onClick="theNext()">&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Update Database">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe this is just a typo in your post, but `setTimeout()` lacks the `delay` value. Hence `getAddress()` is executed right away.

Comment: Why are you using setTimeout?

Comment: Don't actually use the setTimeout on this code. It is used when generating multiple geoCode requests. Have removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by UpdateGeo innerHTML modification.
Whenever you use "innerHTML +=" statements, the current inner controls state is lost and will revert to the original state (eg. to the ones declared statically in html).

You should append the dynamically created element not by string, but by using control.appendChild() as following:

```
var container = document.getElementById('UpdateGeo');
var element = document.createElement('input');
element.setAttribute('type','hidden');
element.setAttribute('name','lat');
element.value = lat;
container.appendChild(element);

element = document.createElement('input');
element.setAttribute('type','hidden');
element.setAttribute('name','lng');
element.value = lng;
container.appendChild(element);
```

instead of

```
var dcHiddenOutput = '<input type="hidden" name="lat" value="' +lat+ '"><input type="hidden" name="lng" value="' +lng+ '">';
document.getElementById("UpdateGeo").innerHTML += dcHiddenOutput;
```

Comment: Thanks LittleSweetSeas, that works perfectly now. Appreciate the help.